# ImageMagick is truncating (squaring) my icons on resize

Tags: conversion, icons, imagemagick, transparency

Trying to resize from 48x48 icon to 16x16 and the resulting file from imagemagick is 16x16 but cut off around the square.

Command:

```
convert -resize "16x16" businessman_add.ico -depth 8 mynew.ico
```

- Original Icon: http://www.workingstorage.com/files/businessman_add.ico
- New Icon: http://www.workingstorage.com/files/mynew.ico

I want the new one to shrink and not get cut off. This is driving me insane.

*Edit:* So I used Photoshop 7 + plugin, IconFX, and Axialis. Turns out that dropping a 48x48 to a 16x16 is going to have a little bit of funky artifacting and cutoffs. I forgot we only have a 16x16 grid to fool with!

Comment: What does the ImageMagick documentation say? Does it support .ico? Is it feasible to use a different program?

Comment: I've scanned and search the docs and it seems to support ico. If I wanted to use a different program I would have specified that in my question.

Comment: Please add your "solved" part as **a real answer** and don't put the answer into the question! Thank you! (you can also accept this in two days from now)

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't see the SUPER in SUPERUSER. I'm just an ordinary guy who knows nothing about images and describes things as they appear to be. No need to be a douchebag.

Answer (score 2):

Those images look perfectly fine to me.  I put both [this](http://www.workingstorage.com/files/businessman_add.ico) and [this](http://www.workingstorage.com/files/mynew.ico) into Photoshop, resized the big one, and compared them - no difference:

[image]

I don't see what's "cut off"...

Comment: Did you use the difference layer feature? And yes, haven't clicked through to them yet but they also appear the same to me just by eye. The rounding of hair and shirt are still there and the `+` sign is still there...

Comment: @Tom Wijsman good idea, I updated the image including the difference between them... It only appears to be differences in colour, nothing else.

Comment: Weird. They seemed cut off in my system, but maybe I'm confusing "cut off" with "scaled to low res"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it's cropping it instead of shrinking it. Try adding `-scale 100%`.

Comment: It's doing kind of a combination of both. It makes it 16x16 but several pixels are cut off around the image.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `"` characters, optionally add a `!` character. See the [geometry documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php?ImageMagick=tmg7m8fd09n9qu2qnm29tpnfe2#geometry).

Answer (score 0):

You should give a try to [IcoFX](http://icofx.ro/), it's a specialized little software with a good GUI that will let you create the 16×16 icon you need in a snap!
(It is also available in a portable version if you don't want install it)